# What's the meaning of 'circ', 'cubic', 'quint', 'quad' in CSS cubic-bezier timing functions?

Tags: css

I find a set of easing functions [here](http://easings.net/). I see the difference, but I've no idea what these names mean
exactly, such as 'ease-in-circ', 'ease-in-quint', 'ease-in-cubic'.

Thanks for some explanation, guys.

Answer (score 2):

"circ" is short for "**circ**ular". The graph of the easing function looks like a quarter circle.

"quad", "cubic", "quart", and "quint" are polynomial easing functions of orders 2, 3, 4, and 5, respectively. That is, they are **quad**ratic, **cubic**, **quart**ic, and **quint**ic functions.

"expo" is an **expo**nential function.

The other function names ("back", "elastic", and "bounce") should all be pretty self-explanatory.